# How to see inbulit classes

Tags: android

I am using android in eclipse . I wanted to see inbuilt classes in android such as 'BaseAdapter' class. Please suggest a method for seeing the content of those classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download the android source code and link it in eclipse. or the easier way is to use http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/